# Restricting field access between two objects of the same type in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, alias

Assume we have the following code:

```
typedef struct {
  int f1;
  int f2;
} t_str;

int f(t_str* p, t_str* q)
{
  p[0].f1++;
  q[0].f2++;
  p[0].f1++;
  q[0].f2++;
  p[0].f1++;
  q[0].f2++;
  p[0].f1++;
  q[0].f2++;
  p[0].f1++;
  q[0].f2++;
  p[0].f1++;
  q[0].f2++;
  p[0].f1++;
  q[0].f2++;
  p[0].f1++;
  q[0].f2++;
  p[0].f1++;
  q[0].f2++;

return 0;
}
```

When we compile it (I used gcc-5.1.0) with -O3 option, the compiler gets the following assembler:

```
f:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    8(%esp), %edx
    movl    4(%esp), %ecx
    movl    4(%edx), %eax
    addl    $9, (%ecx)
    addl    $9, %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%edx)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

That means that gcc decided access to field f1 of p and access to field f2 of q never alias. I guess this comes from assume that two objects of the same type never overlaps or they are the same. But I didn't find the issue in standard.

So please, can anyone find this issue in standard, or another point why gcc restricted field access, or comment what happened?

UPD:

Well, I thought about Paragraph 7 of Section 6.5 too, but it would be more comfortable for me to have something like that in explicit form for all objects:

> 6.5.16.1 Simple assignment
>
> 3 If the value being stored in an object is read from another object
>   that overlaps in any way the storage of the first object, then the
>   overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall have qualified or
>   unqualified versions of a compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Unfortunately this rule can not be used here.

Now look, if for code above I make the following function:

```
void main()
{
    char * c = malloc(12);
    memset(c, 0, 12);
    f((t_str *)(c + 4), (t_str *)c);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", ((t_str *)c)->f1, ((t_str *)c)->f2, ((t_str *)(c + 4))->f2);
}
```

Now I get the following during execution:

```
$ gcc-5.1.0 test1.c -O3 && ./a.out
0 9 0
$ gcc-5.1.0 test1.c -O0 && ./a.out
0 18 0
```

So how do you think is this code valid? Because I'm not shure if it statisfy Paragraph 7 of Section 6.5.

PS: interesting thing:

```
$ gcc-5.1.0 test1.c -O3 -fwhole-program && ./a.out
0 10 0
$ gcc-5.1.0 test1.c -O3 -flto && ./a.out
0 10 0
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. What do you mean with "alias" and "overlap"? What the compiler does seems correct, as long as p and q do not change between accesses (e.g. through the handling of an interrupt or so). I think you could then use the keyword "volatile" to force the compiler to assume they may have changed.

Comment: For extra fun, look at what happens if you declare `int*pf1=&p->f1;int*pf2=&p->f2;` etc and now replace `p->f1++` with `(*pf1)++`.

Comment: alexanius is wondering if the Standard explicitly excludes the possibility for `q` to point to `p->f2`.  Since the `t_str` structure only has 2 `int` members, an array of 2 such structures could be seen as containing a third such structure at address `&p->f2`.  I pretend that it is excluded, but it might be more difficult to make a similar case for `typedef struct { int f[2]; } t_str;`

Comment: @Marc Glisse: it would be interesting to see what `gcc` optimises in this case, but I think it should still be correct to produce the same code, or even something more compact without the load/store via `%eax`

Comment: Same exact code produced by `clang` in both 32 bit and 64 bit x86 code (except for ABI differences)

Answer (score 3):

Paragraph 7 of Section 6.5 of the latest draft (N1570) of C11 reads:

*An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:88)
— a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
— a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
— a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
— a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
— an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
— a character type.*

I interpret this to mean that objects pointed to by `p` and `q` cannot overlap unless they are the same object, because the `t_str` objects are supposed to be accessed by proper pointers.

The Standard is not precise enough to make it clear that `&p->f2` is not a valid pointer to a `t_str` object composed of 2 `int` shared between `p[0]` and `p[1]`. Yet it seems incorrect because the compiler could possibly insert padding between `f1` and `f2` or indeed between `f2` and the end of the structure.

Incidentally, `&p->f2 - &p->f1` is not a valid expression because paragraph 9 of section 6.5.6 Additive operators states this constraint: *When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object;*

If function `f()` took a pointer to `char` as parameter and accessed data via this pointer, `gcc` could not assume this data to be distinct from the `int` members of the structures pointed to by `p` and `q`.  This somewhat counterintuitive exception is the reason why so many C library function prototypes have `restrict` qualifiers on many pointer arguments.  (These qualifiers in function prototypes are merely a hint to the programmer, but do not really tell the compiler anything).

Answer (score 0):

As chqrlie has mentioned, it is unlikely that gcc will let you create a situation where `&p[0].f1 == &q[0].f2`.  That being said, it shouldn't make a difference.  Those operations commute, mathematically.  And the only way that would break down in code is if there is an integer overflow, where again order doesn't matter.  I tested this, and for my compiler (gcc 3.4.6), this optimization appears as soon as I turn on any optimization.

As a counterpoint, consider what happens when we change the struct to

```
typedef struct {
    double f1;
    double f2;
} t_str;
```

In this case, even with -O3, we do not see the increments being combined together, because we could get different answers due to underflow.

Comment: While I agree that the operations commute in the C source, the asm produced by `gcc` breaks this by loading `%eax` before incrementing `(%ecx)` and storing `%eax+9` thereafter.  A more regular asm with `addl    $9, (%edx)` would not make the assumption that `*p` and `*q` do not overlap.